# ImportError occures while importing pytube

Tags: python, stream, quote, pytube

I am facing this error while running a program related to pytube .
as soon as i import this package the error occurs.

```
from pytube import YouTube
```

Error message:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'quote' from 'pytube.compat' (C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\compat.py)

Answer (score 0):

Use pytube3 instead of pytube. Go to your command prompt and type
`pip install pytube3`